# Why is Windows preferring IPv4 when using VPN split tunnel with OpenConnect?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ipv6, openconnect

I am connecting to a VPN using OpenConnect 8.03 on Windows 10. The profile of the VPN only sets a route for the subnet of the VPN. All other IPv4-traffic is still routed via my normal connection. My home setup is dual stacked with IPv4 and IPv6.

If I am not connected to the VPN, IPv6 is preferred over IPv4 as it should be. However, as soon as I connect to the VPN, IPv4 is preferred over IPv6, even for traffic outside the VPN. `route print` shows no difference in the metrics for IPv4 or IPv6 after connecting to the tunnel, except of course it adds a low metric for the single /16 IPv4 subnet of the VPN. Also `netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies` shows no differences. In general, IPv6 still works (confirmed by connecting to IPv6-only hosts or when forcing IPv6).

When I connect to the VPN using OpenConnect on Linux instead of Windows 10, IPv6 is correctly preferred over IPv4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when connected to the IPv4-only VPN, DNS-lookups are done via the IPv4-only connection. In the default configuration, Windows will then only query for A-records, regardless if other interfaces provide IPv6-connectivity.

It is possible to force Windows to query for AAAA-records also on IPv4-only connections. For this, the following registry key needs to be added:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters\

DWORD "AddrConfigControl" = "0"
```

If the value doesn't exist, it needs to be created. No reboot is necessary. The setting will take effect more or less immediately.